# Axial capacitor terminal leads snapped!

Tags: batteries, capacitor, soldering

Unfortunately, while in transport, my capacitor's terminal leads have snapped right to the bottom. What can I do? Can I solder something in their place, so it can work?

Many thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lead was welded to the bottom of the aluminum can.

There's no easy good way to connect to that can without either a spot welder or perhaps conductive epoxy, neither of which would be all that great.

Ordinary solder won't work at all, and getting it hot enough to solder with special aluminum solder/flux would damage the capacitor/

I suggest trying to fit a radial cap in the space, if you can't find another axial one, they're quite cheap. That part also looks very old and electrolytic capacitors do not age well, they're often the first parts to "wear out".

Answer (score 0):

For the price - buy another capacitor.

It may be possible to attach some new leads to the capacitor, depending if the ends are connected to the plates inside.

However, it’s very risky to heat up a capacitor and therefore not recommended. An axial capacitor needs to vent somewhere. If it explodes through over heating you’d better hope it doesn’t vent through the end you are working on.